# How to composite videos and make animations in Ubuntu?

Tags: video-editor, animations, compositing, cinelerra

Well, I'm not talking about programs like NukeX, Cinelerra, Jahshaka because they **aren't** either free or feature rich.
I have seen couple of cool videos done on **Linux platform**, most likely to be Ubuntu.

- [How Linux is Built - Linux Foundation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVpbFMhOAwE)
- [Ubuntu 12.10 Beta Overview - OMG! Ubuntu](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RGZrDiz7uo)

What is the magic application they are using to composit those videos..? Can upcoming **LightWorks** workout these effects...? Is there any Linux native **OpenGL** based application to deal with particles, just like [Particle Illusion for Windows](http://www.wondertouch.com/pillusion3.asp)?

## Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one stop shop, albeit with a steep learning curve, is blender -- it's not only a 3d animation studio, but allows for video-editing as well -- it can be used for rotoscoping work, has support for motion tracking -- the list goes on and on; there is a ppa with very recent versions released regularly:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/irie/blender/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/irie/blender/ubuntu precise main
```

The compositor is a very mighty tool -- if you google a bit, you'll find lots of tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Blender to composite videos and make animations. There are many tutorials on YouTube for doing so, including using particles.

There are also several video editors available, including [NovaCut](http://novacut.com/).